# How to target Internet explorer versions greater than or equal to IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How to target Internet explorer versions greater than or equal to IE 10

I tried this but it does not work with IE11 : `if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1) { //stuff}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use userAgent sniffing, use Feature testing instead.**

please see [https://www.bing.com/search?q=stackoverflow+feature+testing+javascript+IE]

Only IE11 is supported now... all of your site visitors should be using at least IE11. If you are developing/maintaining a company internal website, you use Enterprise Site Mode lists to maintain the backward compatibility of IE11 to use an emulation of an earlier version of IE.

To help you further we would need to inspect/debug your website. If possible include links to your website with your questions.

To test your web apps backward compatibility with older versions of IE, use the Emulation tab of the dev tool to change the Emulation mode of IE 11